# AsyncSelect does not change loading message nor no option message (react-select library)

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I've been trying to customize react-select AsyncSelect loading message and no option message, but so far no luck.

Here's my current code:

```
                    <AsyncSelect
                        noOptionsMessage={() => 'nothing found'}
                        LoadingMessage={() => 'searching...'}
                        cacheOptions
                        loadOptions={searchForPointsOfInterest}
                        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                        getOptionValue={(option) => option}
                        defaultOptions
                        isRtl={true}
                        isClearable={true}
                        placeholder="example"
                        isLoading={isLoading}
                        onChange={onPointOfInterestChange}
                        defaultValue={props.area}
                    />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have prepared the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-8eqj4?file=/example.js). Please, check it out. Except wrong `loadingMessage` prop name i don't see a mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

It should be like

```
<AsyncSelect
    noOptionsMessage={() => 'nothing found'}
    loadingMessage={() => 'searching...'}   //minor type-O here
    cacheOptions
    loadOptions={searchForPointsOfInterest}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
    getOptionValue={(option) => option}
    defaultOptions
    isRtl={true}
    isClearable={true}
    placeholder="example"
    isLoading={isLoading}
    onChange={onPointOfInterestChange}
    defaultValue={props.area} />
```

If your problem not solved add further details of loadOptions and onChange in your question.